# Node.js: how to resolve a circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, circular-dependency

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but my case is specific:

I have three files, a `controller.js`, `router.js` and an `app.js`,

`router.js` imports `controller.js`, `app.js` imports `router.js`

I need to import something from `app.js` to `controller.js`, how would I do that?

Comment: You should not import something from app to controller. If you can move the required code from app.js to another file and import that file in controller.js, you can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes but the function that needs to be imported from app requires code that exists in app that requires code that is in the router.

Comment: This is not designed well. If you designed this, try and accomplish what @Lian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably better off restructuring your code to not need it. Maybe create a third class that uses the other two to accomplish what you need, if you have to use a function in `app.js` you can do like this:

before requiring you should exports `express()` and `functions`

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const func = () => {
  console.log("I'm in App");
};
var exportFiles = module.exports = {
  app: express(),
  func: func,
};
var { app } = exportFiles;
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("server port is 8080")
})
```

**contolers.js**

```
const {func} = require('../app');
```

when you call `func()` in controller result is :

```
func() // I'm in App
```